# Is there a way to get python requests to disable ssl verification through input from user?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',}
response = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, verify=self.ssl)
```

Getting error when passing False as input from command line. It works fine when verify=False is set in the code without passing it as input.

Error:

```
response = requests.get(self.api, headers=headers, verify=self.ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 226, in cert_verify
    "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.add_argument('--ssl', default=True, action="store_false")
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.